# z-index for dropdown menu not working

Tags: css, html

My dropdown menu coming behind my nav bar , I applied z-index , but not supporting. Need suggestions

css

```
 .ChangeColor1{
    z-index:-1    }

.adjTopSide{
        margin-top: -40px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

Html

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right adjTopSide">

      <li class="dropdown" >

          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#/employerProfile" style="background-color: transparent;margin-top:-25px;"> <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" position: absolute" >
     <li ><a href="#/urprofile" style="cursor: pointer;">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="logout()" style="cursor: pointer;">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>                                   
          <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top ChangeColor" >
    </nav>
```

[image: my dropdown menu is coming behind nav bar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this style. if you give z-index then it necessary to give position property.

```
 .adjTopSide{
        margin-top: -40px;
         position: relative;
         z-index: 99;
    }
```

Comment: That should work, or change the markup and put the dropdown under the menu, where it logically belongs.

Comment: yes, but I only provide a solution. as per markup :)

Comment: I already upvoted your answer, so I agree. Just wanted to put a little sugar on top :D